# Check Multiple Values and Change them

Tags: python

Heyo everyone, I have a question.

I have three variables, rF, tF, and dF.
Now these values can range from -100 to +100. I want to check all of them and see if they are less than 1; if they are, set them to 1.

An easy way of doing this is just 3 if statements, like

```
if rF < 1:
    rF = 1
if tF < 1:
    tF = 1
if dF < 1:
    dF = 1
```

However, as you can see, this looks bad, and if i had, say 50 of these values, this could get out of hand quite easily.

I tried to put them in an array like so:

```
for item in [rF, tF, dF]:
if item < 1:
  item = 1
```

However this doesn't work. I believe that when you do that you create a completely different object (the array), and when you change the items you are not changing the variables themselves but the values of the array.

So my question is: What is an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: you could use a dict as an alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use List Comprehension and `max` function.

```
items = [-32, 0, 43]
items = [max(1, item) for item in items]
rF, tF, dF = items
print(rF, tF, dF)
```

Comment: Hahaha thx! This looks so nice. This is what I was looking for.

Comment: if this is satisfactory, please mark as answer to indicate resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a dictionary, if you've only got three variables of which to keep track?

```
rF, tF, dF = 100, -100, 1

d = {'rF': rF, 'tF': tF, 'dF': dF}

for k in d:
    if d[k] < 1:
        d[k] = 1

print(d)
{'rF': 100, 'tF': 1, 'dF': 1}
```

Then if you're referencing any of those values later, you can simply do this (as a trivial example):

```
def f(var):
    print("'%s' is equal to %d" % (var, d[var]))

>>> f('rF')
'rF' is equal to 100
```

If you really wanted to use lists, and you knew the order of your list, you could do this (but dictionaries are made for this type of problem):

```
arr = [rF, tF, dF]
arr = [1 if x < 1 else x for x in arr]

print(arr)
[100, 1, 1]
```

Note that the list comprehension approach won't actually change the values of `rF`, `tF`, and `dF`.

Comment: Well if you print rF, tF, and dF you still get 100, -100, and 1

Comment: Well I mean I could put it in a list -- I'll try that

Comment: That's true. With the list comprehension approach, you wouldn't be changing the actual `rF`, `tF`, and `dF` variables themselves. Do you *have to* use a list? Dictionaries are workhorses when it comes to this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a dictionary and then unpack the dict:

```
d = {'rF': rF, 'tF': tF, 'dF': dF}

for key in d:
    if d[key] < 1:
        d[key] = 1

rF, tF, dF = d['rF'], d['tF'], d['dF']
```

You can use the following instead of the last line:

```
rF, tF, dF = map(d.get, ('rF', 'tF', 'dF'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's exactly what you asked for:

```
rF = -3
tF = 9
dF = -2

myenv = locals()

for k in list(myenv.keys()):
    if len(k) == 2 and k[1] == "F":
        myenv[k] = max(1, myenv[k])

print(rF, tF, dF)
# prints 1 9 1
```

This may accidentally modify any variables you don't really want to change, so I recommend using a proper data structure instead of hacking the user environment.

Edit: Fixed an error for `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. Dictionaries cannot be iterated over *and* modified at the same time. Avoid this by first copying the dictionary keys, and iterating over the original keys instead of the actual dictionary. Should work in Python 2 and 3 now, just Python 2 before.